# Calling setState from callback updates the state in React Context half the time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, react-context

Here is the CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-dream-8lcrt

I have implemented a modal with React context which exposes 1) the open state 2) the modal config 3) an open and close method

```js
// ...

const onOpenDialog = (mode, config) => {
  setDialogMode(mode)
  if (config) {
    setDialogConfig(config);
  }
}

const onCloseDialog = () => {
  setDialogMode("");
  if (Object.keys(dialogConfig).length > 0) {
    setDialogConfig({})
  }
}

// ...

return (
  <Provider value={{ dialogMode, dialogConfig, onOpenDialog, onCloseDialog }}>
    {children}
  </Provider>
)
```

From the main component, I have an onClick handler that call the onOpenDialog method and pass an `onSubmit` and `onClose` callback in its config object (**this onCloseDialog callback is the issue**)

```js
const { onOpenDialog, onCloseDialog } = useDialog()

// ...

const onClick = () => {
  onOpenDialog("add", {
    data: null,
    onSubmit: (data) => {
      console.log("Form Data: ", data)
    },
    onCancel: onCloseDialog
  })
}
```

And finally, I have a FormInModal component that call the two callbacks passed in the dialogConfig object when hitting submit and close.

```js
const onSubmit = (data) => {
  dialogConfig.onSubmit({
    username: data.username,
    password: data.password
  })
}

const onCancel = () => {
  dialogConfig.onCancel()
}
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click on `Open`
2. You should see in the console that 1) The dialog opens 2) The config input that was passed to the Dialog config has data, onSubmit and onCancel, the config input has been set in the dialogConfig state
3. **Click on Cancel, you should see that 1) The dialog closes 2) The dialogConfig state is empty 3) the dialogConfig state is not reseted**

To be fair `3.` works half of the time. This is weird because the dialogConfig state is always updated when the dialog opens. You can see on the React Dev tool that the state update only half the time

Comment: Where is the codesandbox? How we suppose to reproduce?

Comment: You should create a sandbox for this type of question

Comment: I had a CSB ready. Just forgot to add the link... Updated now

Comment: I guess it has to do with something called stale-state due to closure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known problem in React when trying to access the state from a function closures. The old state is captured at the closure creation and returned by the function even though the state has updated.

One way to solve the issue is to access the updated state with:

`setState(previousState => newState)` instead of `setState(newState)`

The answer from the react community: [Function that read an outdated sate](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/22549)